# add products to cart from cms page magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a relatively small problem but I cannot find the solution.

I have a static CMS page which shows a list of products from a category in my Magento store.

I would like to include an add to cart button and a quantity box as well so users can add each product to their shopping cart.

The problem is I have included the add to cart button but when clicked it doesn't add a product to cart. I've read that I need to include the product id into the string but I am displaying more than one product from a category dynamically using a foreach loop....

Is there a workaround or solution to my problem? Any ideas will be welcomed.

Here's the code:

```
              <?php 
$category_id = "49"; // category_id for "Accessories"
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description'), 'inner')
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id));
?>
<?php if($_productCollection->count()): ?>
  <ul class="media-list pull-left">
   <?php 
   $products = array();
   foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) { 
    ?>
    <li class="media">
      <a class="fancybox pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220, 200); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
        <img class="media-object"  src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(100, 100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading"><a class="view-item-button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Order'); ?> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?><?php echo $this->__('&#8482;'); ?></a></h4>
      <div class="media">
       <?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
       <h6>Price <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());; ?></h6>
       <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
       <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
     <?php else: ?>
     <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
   <?php endif; ?>

 </div>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
</ul> 
<script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script><?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Comment: you are missing form tag in your code so how can it submit your form, just look in list.phtml or view.phtml file for product, then you can easily get idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to add a product to cart by using the following block code:

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list_related" category_id="49" template="PATH_TO_TEMPLATE_FILE"}}
```

Then add a a checkout button to the file and it works!

```
`<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?> `
```

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f   Your code also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use querystrings to achieve this, as explained [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring)

Comment: using query strings wouldn't help as I am using a foreach to echo each product from one category.

Answer (score 0):

```
                 <?php 
$category_id = 49; // category_id for "Accessories"
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<?php if($_productCollection->count()): ?>
  <ul class="media-list pull-left">
   <?php 
   $products = array();
   foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) { 
    ?>
    <li class="media">
      <a class="fancybox pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220, 200); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
        <img class="media-object"  src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(100, 100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading"><a class="view-item-button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Order'); ?> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?><?php echo $this->__('&#8482;'); ?></a></h4>
      <div class="media">
       <?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
       <h6>Price <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice());; ?></h6>
       <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
       <form id="addtocartform_<?=$_product->getId()?>" action="<?=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product)?>">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$_product->getId()?>" name="product" id="product"/>
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span>Add To Cart</span></span></button>
       </form>
     <?php else: ?>
     <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
   <?php endif; ?>

 </div>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
</ul>  
<?php endif; ?>
```